# How to create a read-only entity using Jhipster?

Tags: java, jpa, jhipster, jdl

I have an existing view in a relational database and I'd like to add it as an existing entity in the model with jhipster using jdl-import.
How can I mark the entity as readOnly using jdl-import generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in JDL nor in entity sub generator, you must do it manually in code after generation.

Comment: Do I need to add an attribute to the json generated entity? And what is the attribute?

Comment: When I said manually I meant in code  not in json. There's not support in jhipster for this

Comment: I've added the read-only entity manually in the code as you suggested. Is it possible to include it in the jdl model?

Comment: No as I said before.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from JHipster 6.4.0, it is possible to define an Entity as readonly in JDL.

When defining you Entity in JDL, you can define it as readonly by using an annotation:

```
@readOnly
entity MyEnity {
}
```

Or by using an option:

```
entity MyEntity {
}

readOnly MyEntity
```

The release notes of 6.4.0 can be found [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/2019/10/10/jhipster-release-6.4.0.html#jhipster-release-v640).

The JDL documentation also includes a section explaining hoy the `readOnly` annotation/option can be used: https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/options

Hope it helps,